# Lock-free FIFO queue implementation

Tags: c, thread-safety, queue, lock-free

```
struct __fifo_node_t {
        void *next;
};
typedef struct __fifo_node_t fifo_node_t;

struct __fifo_list_t {
        void *next;
        void *tail;
};
typedef struct __fifo_list_t fifo_list_t;

static inline void __fifo_list_push(fifo_list_t *head, fifo_node_t *node)
{
        fifo_node_t *prev;

        node->next = head;
        prev = atomic_xchg64(&head->tail, node);
        prev->next = node;
}

static inline fifo_node_t *__fifo_list_pop(fifo_list_t *head)
{
        fifo_node_t *node;
        while ((node = ACCESS_ONCE(head->next)) != head) {
                fifo_node_t *next = ACCESS_ONCE(node->next);
                if (cmpxchg_eq(&head->next, node, next) == node) {
                        if (cmpxchg_eq(&head->tail, node, head) != node &&
                            next == head)
                                while (ACCESS_ONCE(head->next) == next)
                                        head->next = ACCESS_ONCE(node->next);
                        return node;
                }
        }
        return NULL;
}

static inline void __fifo_list_init(fifo_list_t *head)
{
        head->next = head->tail = head;
}
```

---

`atomic_xchg64` - Atomic exchange 64bit with new value and return the old value

`cmpxchg_eq` - Atomic compare and exchange 64bit with new value and return the old value

`ACCESS_ONCE` - `(*(volatile typeof(x) *)&(x))`

Can you review it? Is this implementation thread-safe ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

#### The meaning of lock-free

Although your program is free of locks in the traditional sense, "lock free programming" typically describes a style of programming with certain guarantees.  One of these guarantees is that even if one or more threads are suspended indefinitely, other threads can continue to make progress.  [This wikipedia article on Non-blocking algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) describes "lock-free" and "wait-free" programming in more detail.

In your code, if one thread is permanently suspended between these two lines:

> ```
>     prev = atomic_xchg64(&head->tail, node);
>     prev->next = node;
> ```

then some other thread will spin forever in this loop:

> ```
>                             while (ACCESS_ONCE(head->next) == next)
>                                     head->next = ACCESS_ONCE(node->next);
> ```

and furthermore, no nodes past the node that the suspended thread "half-pushed" will be able to be popped.

#### ABA problem

Additionally, your code falls victim to the [ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).  Consider an initial situation with two nodes in your FIFO:

```
A -> B    (head->next = A, head->tail = B)
```

Suppose thread #1 calls `__fifo_list_pop()`, and gets to this line:

> ```
>             if (cmpxchg_eq(&head->next, node, next) == node) {
> ```

Here, `node` will be `A`, and `next` will be  `B`, and the code is about to atomically change `head->next` from `A` to `B`.

Now suppose thread #1 is descheduled, and in the meantime, other threads pop both `A` and `B` off the FIFO, and then push `A` and `C` back on the FIFO.  Now, your FIFO looks like this:

```
A -> C    (head->next = A, head->tail = C)
```

If thread #1 now wakes up, it will perform the atomic exchange, causing `head->next` to point at `B` which isn't even alive any more:

```
A -> B    (but B was already popped and is now dead)
```

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: I always working on kernel mode (no-preemption, disabled-irq) or cavium octeon simple executive mode, and ignored scheduling of process.

Comment: @ShadowStar If you have no preemption and interrupts disabled, then the first section about deadlocking won't happen.  But you can still get the ABA problem if you encounter a rare set of timings.  Basically, there is a memory delay between a write on one core and its visibility on another core, and if the timings work out just the wrong way, the ABA problem will occur.

Comment: Yes, there is ABA problem in theory.